# Delete selected items in a ListView from SQLite Database using Xamarin.Android C#

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.android, sql-delete, delete-row

Using Xamarin.Android C#, how can I delete selected items in a ListView (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked)? The items are from SQLite Database.

The link of UI image source: https://www.screencast.com/t/fe9oXu0wB4e

**Code:**

```
...

    //ADAPTER
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked,
        tvShows);
    sp.Adapter = adapter;
    sp.ChoiceMode = Android.Widget.ChoiceMode.Multiple;

    //EVENTS
    saveBtn.Click += saveBtn_Click;
    deleteBtn.Click += deleteBtn_Click;
    sp.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, tvShows[e.Position], ToastLength.Short).Show();
    };

}

void sp_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, tvShows[e.Position], 
        Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue trying to achieve essentially the same thing as you.